# Access JSON file in Lakehouse from Microsoft Notebook with other Lakehouse-Default

Tags: pyspark, microsoft-fabric, data-lakehouse

I have a Microsoft Notebook based on my SILVER-Lakehouse. There I want to access a JSON-File from my BRONZE-Lakehouse.

Doing so with absolute path works:

```
 # Import all files from bronze folder of lakehouse via absolute path
 df = spark.read.json("abfss://SomeWorkspace@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/Bronze.Lakehouse/Files/raw/")
```

But I'd prefer to have like a relative path:

```
# Would be nice to like relativley address the Bronze-Lakehouse, but that doesn't seem to work
#df = spark.read.json("/Bronze.Lakehouse/Files/raw/")
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just create a [shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/onelake/onelake-shortcuts) to the target folder in your local SILVER-Lakehouse.